# Set initial value of Spinner based upon selected rows column value in SQLite table

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

I am new to android programming so apologies for any misuse of technical jargon. I have a spinner which has a text value of `league_name` and an id of `id` from the `leagues` SQLite table.

### Example of leagues table design

```
id  |  league_name
-----------------
1   |  Northern Premier Division
2   |  Southern League 1
3   |  Northern Division 2
```

I also have a `teams` table storing information on a team and a lookup table joining the id's of the `teams` and `leagues` table called `teams_vs_leagues`. So the selected value of this spinner gets inserted into the `league_id` column in the `teams_vs_leagues` table. I have an edit page to edit an individual teams record, which includes selecting a league from the spinner. However it always defaults to first available `id` in this case `1`. Although, I want the initial value of the spinner to be the selected `league_id` in the `teams_vs_leagues` which corresponds to the `team_id` you are currently viewing. So if the selected `team_id` had a `league_id` of `3` I want the initial value of the spinner to be `Northern Division 2`.

### UpdateTeam Class

```
public class UpdateTeam extends AppCompatActivity {

 ArrayList < Team > imageArry = new ArrayList < Team > ();
 TeamUpdateAdapter adapter;
 Button updateButton;
 DatabaseHelper myDb;
 EditText teamNameEdit;
 ImageView teamImage;
 Spinner league; //Create Spinner Variables to cast in OnCreate method

 ArrayList < String > leagues = new ArrayList < String > (); //Create Array List to bind to Spinner
 ArrayAdapter < String > arrayAdapter; //Declare Array Adapter

 long leagueId; //Declare global long for league_id
 long id; //Declare global long for team_id

 String picturePath = ""; //Create String variable for image path to be stored in db table

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.edit_team);

  myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

  updateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);

  //Call Spinner Variable and cast spinner id reference
  league = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.edit_league_id);

  //Call Array Adapter to Bind Array list data to Spinner
  arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, leagues);

  //get selected teams values from intent
  id = getIntent().getLongExtra("TEAM", 0 l);
  final String editTeamName = getIntent().getStringExtra("TEAM_NAME");
  picturePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("IMAGE");
  leagueId = getIntent().getLongExtra("LEAGUE_ID", 01);
  //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Leagueid = " + leagueId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  teamNameEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTeamName);
  teamNameEdit.setText(editTeamName, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

  // Reading all teams from database
  final List < Team > team = myDb.getTeam((int) id);
  for (Team tm: team) {
   String log = "ID:" + tm.getId() + " Team Name: " + tm.getTeamName() + " ,Image: " + tm.getPath() + " ,Points: " + tm.getPoints() + " ,League Name: " + tm.getLeagueName() + " ,League ID: " + tm.getLeagueId();

   // Writing teams to log
   Log.d("Result: ", log);
   //add teams data in arrayList
   imageArry.add(tm);
  }
  adapter = new TeamUpdateAdapter(this, R.layout.update_team,
   imageArry);
  ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list_view);
  dataList.setAdapter(adapter);

  //call loadSpinnerData method
  loadSpinnerData();

  //call updateTeam
  updateTeam();

  //call selectLeague
  selectLeague();


 }

 private void loadSpinnerData() {
  // Spinner Drop down elements
  List < Leagues > leagueList = myDb.getAllLeagues();
  // Creating adapter for spinner
  ArrayAdapter < Leagues > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < Leagues > (this,
   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, leagueList);
  // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  // attaching data adapter to spinner
  league.setAdapter(adapter);
 }

 public void selectLeague() {
  //set onItemSelected Listener for spinner
  league.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView < ? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    //get selected league id
    leagueId = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(((Leagues) league.getSelectedItem()).getId()));
   }

   @Override
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView < ? > parent) {

   }
  });
 }

 //Create addTeam method to add new team to db
 public void updateTeam() {
  updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    if (myDb.updateTeam(
      id,
      teamNameEdit.getText().toString(),
      picturePath,
      leagueId)) {

     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Update successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     Intent intent =
      new Intent(UpdateTeam.this, DisplayTeam.class);
     startActivity(intent);
    } else
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Update failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
  });
 }
}
```

### Leagues Class

```
public class Leagues {

 //Declare Global String & int
 private int id;
 private String leagueName;

 /*********** Set Methods ******************/
 public Leagues(int id, String leagueName) {
  this.id = id;
  this.leagueName = leagueName;
 }

 public void setId(int id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 public void setLeagueName(String leagueName) {
  this.leagueName = leagueName;
 }

 /*********** Get Methods ****************/
 public int getId() {
  return this.id;
 }

 public String getLeagueName() {
  return this.leagueName;
 }

 //Provides string value to display in Spinner
 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return leagueName;
 }
}
```

### getAllLeagues method

```
public List < Leagues > getAllLeagues() {
 List < Leagues > labels = new ArrayList < Leagues > ();
 // Select All Query
 String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + LEAGUES_TABLE;

 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

 // looping through all rows and adding to list
 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
  do {
   labels.add(new Leagues(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1)));
  } while (cursor.moveToNext());
 }

 // closing connection
 cursor.close();
 db.close();

 // returning labels
 return labels;
}
```

If you need any further information, do not hesitate to leave a comment. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the selected league object to getPosition() method of the array adapter

```
int index = arrayAdapter.getPosition(SELECTED_LEAGUE_ID);
league.setSelection(index);
```

Comment: When I set `int index = arrayAdapter.getPosition(String.valueOf(leagueId));
        league.setSelection(index);` I am always getting a value of `1` despite if I select a team that should have a value of `2` or `3`

Comment: My apologies, I always get a value of `-1`